# Two definitions of invariant polynomial on $n\times n$ complex matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, differential-geometry, polynomials

Let $M_n(\Bbb C)$ be the algebra consisting of all $n\times n$ complex matrices. An invariant polynomial on $M_n(\Bbb C)$ is a polynomial function $P:M_n(\Bbb C)\to \Bbb C$ satisfying $P(XY)=P(YX)$.

I am trying to show that this condition is equivalent to $P(AXA^{-1})=P(X)$ for every nonsingular $A$. Clearly $P(XY)=P(YX)$ for all $X,Y$ implies $P(AXA^{-1})=P(X)$. But why is the converse true?

(This definition occurs in Milnor's *Characteristic Classes*, Appendix C.)

Comment: If $Y$ is invertible, then $P(XY)=P(YXYY^{-1})=P(YX)$. But, what to do if $Y$ isn't invertible?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165739/how-to-prove-i-t-x-is-invertiable-for-small-enough-t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polynomial functions are continuous. Let $Y_t=Y+tI$. When $t\ne0$ is small, $Y_t$ is invertible. Therefore $P(XY_t)=P(Y_t(XY_t)Y_t^{-1})=P(Y_tX)$. Now let $t\to0$ to finish.

Comment: How do we know that $Y+tI$ is invertible for small $t$?

Comment: @probably123 $\det(Y+tI)$ is, up to a sign, a monic (hence nonzero) non-constant polynomial in $t$. Therefore the polynomial equation $\det(Y+tI)=0$ it has only finitely many zeroes. Put it another way, if $(Y+tI)v=0$ for some nonzero vector $v$, then $Yv=-tv$, i.e. $-t$ is an eigenvalue of $Y$. However, a matrix has only finitely many eigenvalues. Therefore $t$ cannot be an eigenvalue of $Y$ when $|t|$ lies strictly between $0$ and the smallest nonzero eigenvalue (if any) of $Y$.

Answer (score 0):

$P(AXA^{-1})=P(X)$ implies $P(AX)=P(XA)$ for all nonsingular $A$.

Remember that nonsingular matrixes are dense in $M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$, implying every singular matrix have nonsingular approximation, that is, for any singular $T$, there exists nonsingular $T_{n}$ such that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\Vert T_{n}-T\Vert=0$$
The rest of the proof should be easy to finish.